# Java String get multiple index values

Tags: java, string, indexof

Rather than using "split" method, is there any easy way to get all the index values of double quote character ("") on following String. Thanks.

```
String command = "-u User -P Password mkdir \"temp dir\" rmdir \"host dir\"";
int[] indexAll = command.indexOf ("\""); // This line of code is not compile, only I expect this kind of expression
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built in method that does this.

Use the overloaded [`String#indexOf(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-int-) method that accepts a starting position. Keep looping until you get -1, always providing the result of the previous call as the starting position. You can add each result in a `List` and convert that to an `int[]` later.

Alternatively, use `Pattern` and `Matcher`, looping while `Matcher#find()` returns a result.

Here are a few examples:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String command = "-u User -P Password mkdir \"temp dir\" rmdir \"host dir\"";
    List<Integer> positions = new LinkedList<>();
    int position = command.indexOf("\"", 0);

    while (position != -1) {
        positions.add(position);
        position = command.indexOf("\"", position + 1);
    }
    System.out.println(positions);

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(command);
    positions = new LinkedList<>();

    while (matcher.find()) {
        positions.add(matcher.start());
    }

    System.out.println(positions);
}
```

prints

```
[26, 35, 43, 52]
[26, 35, 43, 52]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to Sotirios method, but you can avoid converting back to array, by first finding number of occurrences so that you can initialize array.

```
String command = "-u User -P Password mkdir \"temp dir\" rmdir \"host dir\"";
int count = command.length() - command.replace("\"", "").length();
int indexAll[] = new int[count];
int position = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  position = command.indexOf("\"", position + 1);
  indexAll[i] = position;
}
```

Comment: Works the same but i think using `StringUtils.countMatches`
 is neater, `int indexAll[] = new int[StringUtils.countMatches(command,"\"")];` but that's just preference.
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#countMatches(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)